# Exception parsing XML file on AWS S3

Tags: xml, scala, amazon-s3

When I parse an XML file on AWS S3, I get an exception.  When I parse the same file on my hard drive, it works fine.

Here is how I parse the file on AWS S3:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3
import scala.io.{BufferedSource, Source}
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest

  private def loadNode(s3Client: AmazonS3, bucket: String, filePath: String) = {
    val s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, filePath))

    val source: BufferedSource = Source.fromInputStream(s3Object.getObjectContent)
    val joinedLines = source.mkString
    val node = Try(xml.XML.loadString(joinedLines))

    node
  }
```

When I do so, I get the following exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Here is how I load the file locally:

```
val xml = XML.loadFile("/Users/paulreiners/data/my-file.xml")
```

This works just fine.

When I executing the following code:

```
System.out.println("Content-Type: " + s3Object.getObjectMetadata.getContentType)
```

it prints:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

I don't know if that is helpful.

So what is going wrong in the S3 case?

Comment: Var joinedLines contains invalid character or empty line at the beginning. Try to print it on S3 surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling getLines on the return value of getObjectContent.

```
val s3Object= s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("myBucket", "myPath/myFile.xml"))
val myData = Source.fromInputStream(s3Object.getObjectContent()).getLines()
println(s"got xml: $myData")
val node = Try(xml.XML.loadString(myData))
```